# Create dynamic search box instead of Ctrl + F

Tags: search, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’d like to create a dynamic search box at the top of my master sheet (Sheet 1) instead of using the “Find” command, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. It would search column B and output info from the corresponding cell in column C.

The search box/cell would be dynamic, so as I type into it, it would pre-populate from a master list (Sheet 2), without having to hit `ENTER` or an `OK` button.

I’d like the search box/cell to be in A1

I’d like it to search column B data. From B2 to the end (row can change): `B2:B`

The result would be the data in column C:`C2:C`

Not sure if I should use the `QUERY` or `ARRAYFORMULA` function. Appreciate any thoughts on how to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out!

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q_fS9Z2p8j9Mg4lB0psn3vDfLedYtSNEfgIkGUkQcbw/edit?usp=sharing)

Search Box (A1): I used `Data Validation`. It is dynamic as I type and lists the master list of items in column A

Search Results (B1): I used `VLOOKUP`

Thanks, @player0, for suggesting the data validation! Really helped :)

Only issue is that I sometimes have multiple values in Column B (Item). For instance, I have "lemon" listed twice. I'd like the output in `B1`to show all other results. They can show in B2...Any suggestions?

EDIT: For the issue of multiples in column B, I decided to change all items in Column B to a unique identifier.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10), QUERY({B2:C}, "select Col2 where Col1 contains '"&A1&"'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEh-TxxrY8QPTOBdybIfv59cBm8dXnU3yNJzZmfEGYE/edit#gid=0)

Comment: that works! wish i saw this earlier before i changed all values in column B to be unique LOL thanks again for this. it's brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

paste this in **C2** cell:

```
=QUERY({B2:B}, "where Col1 contains '"&A1&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

and set up dropdown data validation from **B2:B** range in **A1** cell

[image: 0]

---

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16zWtfF582oOlP6oLOS3lhcNDw5ffrWIt20L3AzepipY/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @player0- thanks for uploading the demo doc. unfortunately, it didnt quite work the way i needed it to. i actually have columns up to L with data throughout. when i pasted the formula into C2, the error message said it was preventing writing over data in column C3, etc i'll upload a sample sheet to play with

Comment: you need to delete whole C column and then paste formula in C2. found results needs to be rolled out and they can do so only in empty cells

Comment: i think i figured it out! see my answer below

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't help.if you check out my answer below, i show what i was looking for. the only issue now is that i have multiple items that are the same in column B, but the output in B1 only shows one result; it's missing all other results. any idea how to have these show as well? appreciate your help!

Comment: my solution for the multiples is to make all items in column B unique